# ¿Alguien puede decirme que hacer con mi codigo?

Tags: java, switch, bluej, usecase

buenas les comento que mi problema es con un código de java el cual tengo que salen errores en los switch-case y no me deja compilarlo, son más o menos en la línea 15-18 y 53-56; el problema habla sobre medir la hemoglobina en una persona acorde a su edad en meses y anos, cree un if debajo de un switch para que separara los case en si y no, para ya despues preguntar bien su edad y medir su hemoglobina y decidir si tiene anemia o no(el if debajo del switch lo puse ya que lo vi en un video ya que mi maestra no nos esta ensenando nada y tengo que descubrir las cosas por mi propia cuenta), aquí les dejo mi código, perdonen si tengo otras cosas mal o el codigo se ve inapropiado o largo, apenas estoy aprendiendo

````
public class PR {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner dato= new Scanner(System.in);
        String n, a, s, o, m;
        float  e, he, ed;
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        n= dato.nextln();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su sexo (masculino o femenino):" );
        s= dato.nextln();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nivel de hemoglobina");
        he=dato.nextFloat();
        System.out.printl("Su edad es en meses o en anos (Ingrese si en caso de que sea en meses y no en caso de que sea en anos)");
        m=dato.next();
        switch(m){
            if (m==Si&&m==si&&m==SI){
            case"Si": case "SI": case "si":
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad de 0 a 12 meses: ");
            ed=dato.nextFloat();
            if ((e=1)&&((he>=13)&&(he<=26))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed);
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if ((he<13)&&(he>26)){;
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed);
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
            }
            if (((e>1)&&(e<=6))&&((he>=10)&&(he<=18))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed);
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if((he<10)&&(he>18)){}; 
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed);
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
            }
             if (((e>6)&&(e<=12))&&((he>=11)&&(he<=15))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed); 
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if((he<11)&&(he>15)){};
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed );
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
            }
            break;
            if (m==No&&m==NO&&m==no)
            case "No": case "no": case "NO":
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad de 1 a 15 anos: ");
            ed=dato.nextFloat();
            if (((ed>=1)&&(ed<=5))&&((he>=11.5)&&(he<=15))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed); 
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if((he<11.5)&&(he>15)){};
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed );
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
                if (((e>5)&&(e<=10))&&((he>=12.6)&&(he<=15.5))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed); 
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if((he<12.6)&&(he>15.5)){};
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed );
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
                if (((e>10)&&(e<=15))&&((he>=13)&&(he<=15.5))){
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed); 
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s); 
                System.out.println("no tiene anemia");
                if((he<13)&&(he>15.5)){};
                System.out.println("El paciente: " + n);
                System.out.println("con la edad de: " + ed );
                System.out.println("meses y del sexo: " + s);
                System.out.println("si tiene anemia");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error, introduzca bien los datos");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Te sobran los if de m=Si y m=No. Para empezar entre switch(m) { espera un case, ninguna otra cosa enmedio es valida.

Comment: m==Si&&m==si&&m==SI  ==> esa condición está mal debes cambiar por ||, no poder ser todo eso a la vez (deberías hacer un toUpperCase()). Tambien tienes unos if mal cerrado. A modo de concejo (si es que estas estudiando algo relacionado con informática, de lo contrario no seguir leyendo) : NO puedes anidar esa cantidad de if y switch, siempre te va dar errores, todo ese código se puede hacer en la mitad de líneas o menos, repites las salidas de la consola

Comment: @Yussef Técnicamente, se pueden anidar cuantos if y switch necesites, decir que no se puede es falso, puesto que el lenguaje lo permite... Es poco mantenible, horrible de leer y hace repetir código? Si, si y obviamente si, pero *se puede hacer*? También si

Comment: @Benito-B Estimado, tienes toda la razón. Modismos de mi país que a veces saltan sin que me dé cuenta. Acá decimos "no puedes" como sinónimo a que "nunca, en ningún caso, deberías hacer algo".

Comment: @Yussef En España también se usa de esa manera, pero al tratar temas técnicos es mejor ser lo más explícito posible, puesto que perfectamente puede hacerse (y cuando estás aprendiendo a programar, muchas veces es la única manera en que sabes hacer algo! Y eso está bien, lo importante es ir aprendiendo, ya aprenderán a hacerlo mejor :))